# Get one record for all group?

Tags: mysql

```
id | group | text
1  | 1     | sadsd
2  | 1     | sdffs
3  | 1     | sdffs
4  | 2     | sdf
5  | 2     | sdfs
6  | 3     | sdfsdf
7  | 4     | 243
8  | 4     | dfgd
```

How can i get with SQL all group, but only one? I would like show:

```
group:
1
2
3
4
```

Other example:

```
id | group | text
1  | v     | sadsd
2  | b     | sdffs
3  | n     | sdffs
4  | v     | sdf
5  | v     | sdfs
6  | n     | sdfsdf
7  | m     | 243
8  | b     | dfgd
```

How can i get with SQL all group, but only one? I would like show:

```
group:
v
b
n
m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a list of all groups, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT ..`

```
SELECT DISTINCT `group` FROM yourTable;
```

If you want to select some additional data as well, you should use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT `group` FROM yourTable GROUP BY `group`;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `group` FROM `groupTable` GROUP BY `group`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
SELECT group 
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY group
```